# Writing c++ dll with Qt GUI, displaying fails in custom widget

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I am writing a dll for an application that I cannot modify. This application is sending requests to my dll and I can run this application in single request mode or automatic where it works in some kind of loop sending requests and processing responses. I am not aware of how exactly this automatic mode works and I don't have access to source code to see the difference.

In my dll I have a custom MainWindow class inheriting QMainWindow that contains two objects: LogWindow inheriting QPlainTextEdit, and custom Widget inheriting QWidget. I would like to display some text and change some properties in my widget on request from main application. It all works well with single request. However, in automatic mode only the text is updated. I need some help to also make updates in widget. Now some implementation details:

In my dll code I have global variables for application and main window:

```
QApplication * app = nullptr; 
MainWindow * win = nullptr;
```

I create them on loading of the dll:

```
app = new QApplication(*argc, argv);
win = new MainWindow;
win->show();
app->processEvents();
```

My MainWindow looks like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(this, &MainWindow::message_received, ui->log_window, &LogWindow::appendMessage);
    connect(this, &MainWindow::colors_received, ui->custom_widget, &CustomWidget::set_colors);
}

void MainWindow::append_log(std::string const & str) {
    emit message_received(QString::fromStdString(str));
}
void MainWindow::display_colors(Colors const & colors) {
    emit colors_received(colors);   
}
```

I call 'append_log()' and 'display_colors()' on request from application. And these are the slots being called:

```
void LogWindow::appendMessage(const QString & message) {
    this->appendPlainText(message);
}
```

And in Custom Widget:

```
void CustomWidget::set_colors(Colors const & colors) {
    setStyleSheet("background-color: red");
}
```

On request from dll I am calling both  'win->append_log()' and 'win->display_colors()'. As I said in automatic mode only text gets displayed, but no update to colors. I am guessing PlainTextEdit::appendPlainText() method must be calling some update, but I cannot figure out how to duplicate the behaviour onto my class. I tried 'update()' and 'repaint()' but nothing seems to work.

I guess noone had similar problem before, but I would appreciate some suggestions on what to try or where to look for.

### Update

Turns out that `CustomWidget::set_colors()` method is not called when running in "automatic" mode. I assumed it is called, because I am using exactly the same method to call it as with `LogWindow::appendMessage()`.

Now the question is why it is not called. Some code details:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void append_log(std::string const &);
    void display_colors(Colors const &);
signals:
    void message_received(QString const &);
    void colors_received(Colors const &);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

class LogWindow : public QPlainTextEdit
{
public:
    LogWindow();
    LogWindow(QWidget * parent);
public slots:
    void appendMessage(QString const &);
};

class CustomWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CustomWidget(QWidget *);
    CustomWidget(QWidget *, Colors);

public slots:
    void set_colors(Colors const &);

};
```

From generated `setupUi()` function:

```
centralWidget = new QWidget(MainWindow);
centralWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("centralWidget"));
log_window = new LogWindow(centralWidget);
log_window->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("log_window"));
log_window->setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 421, 561));
custom_widget = new CustomWidget(centralWidget);
custom_widget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("custom_widget"));
custom_widget->setGeometry(QRect(439, 9, 381, 331));
MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
```

Probably I am missing something, but to me it looks like both methods are called exactly the same way. Unfortunately only one of them is working. Looking for suggestions what could be the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that `setStyleSheet()` is called in "automatic mode" ? If it works when you call it "manually" , it would suggest that it is not called at all when it does not work.

Comment: @BenjaminT Thanks for the suggestion! It was indeed the issue. I assumed it would be called because both methods look exactly the same. I added `std::abort()` instead of `setStyleSheet()` and it only crashed in "manual" mode, but not in "automatic". However, this doesn't resolve my issue: I still don't know why it's not called. I updated the question with some more code.

Comment: You have not explain the difference between "automatic" and "manual". What action do you do? What function is called? Also my previous comment still holds (recursively): are you sure that the `colors_received()` signal is called (emitted) ? You have to follow up the calls until you find an error. And instead of std::abort() use a debugger or at least `qDebug()`.

Comment: `MainWindow::display_colors()` is called, and it is emitting `colors_received()`. The problem must be that for some reason signal is not triggering the slot.
As I mentioned, my dll is run by application that I cannot modify, I only have *.exe file and a basic manual what dll functions it imports/exports. I also don't know how exactly "automatic" mode works, only that it is some continous flow, compared to "manual" which is returning.
For the reasons above I also cannot debug (or at least don't know how) and don't have a steam for `qDebug()`

Comment: If the signal is emitted and the slot is not called that means they are not connected. Have you checked the return value of `QObject::connect()`?

Comment: I just checked, connection works well: `QObject::conect() == true`. Also, the slot is being called in "manual" mode.

Comment: If the signal is emitted but the slot not called, that means that the connection is broken. This can be because the receiver has been deleted and recreated. Maybe you can check using `QObject::disconnectNotify()`. Or using `receivers()` just before emitting the signal to be sure  you have a valid connection.

Comment: I implemented `QObject::disconnectNotify()`, it is not called at any point. Also `receivers(SIGNAL(colors_received(Colors const &)));` returns 1 and `isSignalConnected` returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slot/signal mechanism was not working with custom class `Colors`, because it was not registered in Qt Meta Object system. Adding this line before signal connection solved the problem:

```
qRegisterMetaType<Colors>("Colors");
```